# How to create empty signature line in org mode?

Tags: org-mode, org-export

I often create legal documents by using GNU Emacs Org Mode. And I would like to have something like ______________________ as an empty line for signature:

Authorized person: Mr. Joe Doe

Signature: _______________________

And I wish to export as PDF, naturally through LaTeX, as those are legal documents.

Comment: You might want to include a bit more detail. For example, what are you ultimately exporting your org file to? LaTeX? HTML? PDF?

Comment: as LaTeX and PDF naturally

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wrapping the underscore characters in tilde or equals signs seems to work:

> Here's a test with tildes: ~_______~
>
> And another test, with equals: =______=

You can also use raw LaTeX, e.g.,

> Here's a test with a LaTeX macro: \rule{1cm}{0.5pt}